# Fractional Matrix Power in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, incanter, colt

I am trying working with transition matricies in clojure.  In converting say an annual bond rating transition matrix to quarterly, I need 0.25 power of a square matrix.

In python, we have the [fractional_matrix_power from scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power.html) as:

```
>>> from scipy.linalg import fractional_matrix_power
>>> a = np.array([[1.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0]])
>>> b = fractional_matrix_power(a, 0.5)
>>> b
array([[ 0.75592895,  1.13389342],
       [ 0.37796447,  1.88982237]])
```

In searching [Incanter](http://incanter.org/) and [Parallel Colt](https://github.com/rwl/ParallelColt) I have yet to find anything.  Wading through javadocs and google searches have not helped but maybe "matrix" and "power" are too generic to drill down to what I am looking for.

I do I really need to [transcode a python](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/linalg/_matfuncs_inv_ssq.py#L676) or R function or is there some cool colt doc site I'm missing?

Comment: You're asking for an existing off-site JVM implementation of fractional matrix power, correct? In that case, I believe this question is off-topic. In any case, from the small bit of research I've done, it looks like you will indeed need to transcode from a non-JVM implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You may have already seen [the core.matrix library for Clojure](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix).  It is focused on basic linear algebra and does not have (yet!) a matrix exponent function as you are describing.

However, if you did transcode the above algorithm from Python to Clojure, I am sure it would be a welcome addition to `core.matrix`.

You should also look into [the Neanderthal project](http://neanderthal.uncomplicate.org/), which is focused on using the GPU for matrix operations.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  I started to transcode but hit pause when the algos called for Schur decomposition.  There is one in Apache.commons math3 but is is not public so I couldn't get to it from clojure.  Neanderthal is interesting because the mkl libraries have schur but is is not currently exposed to clojure.  I would move more confidently if I knew where some of the algorythmic code should live. Incanter, Neanderthal, core.matrix, apache.commons... clojure, java, c...?  In python, scipy is the answer but in clojure, I'm not sure.